# Different geom_point shapes in ggplot2 conditional on factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a forest plot for a project that I'm working on. The thing I'm struggling to achieve is having a filled shape for 'significant' results and a hollow shape for 'non-significant' results. I've tried to format a reproducible example below, which replicates the issue I'm having.

First a data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

##data frame
df <- tibble('outcome.var' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 
'J'),
   'coefficient' = c(-0.08, -0.01, -0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, -0.08, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
   'conf.low' = c(-0.12, -0.03, -0.09, 0.01, 0.02,  0.01, -0.10, -0.2, 0.05, 0.1),
   'conf.high' = c(-0.05, 0.02, -0.03, 0.03, -0.01, 0.04, -0.06, 0, 0.2, 0.3),
   'p.value' =c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04)) %>%
  mutate(significant = as.factor(ifelse(p.value > 0.05, 'nonsig', 'sig')),
     label = case_when(
      .$outcome.var %in% c('A', 'B', 'C') ~ 'First',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('D', 'E', 'F') ~ 'Second',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('G', 'H') ~ 'Third',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('I', 'J') ~ 'Fourth'))
```

Then the forest plot. I would like the points to be filled if the `df$significant` variable is <= 0.05, or hollow if >0.05. Though the legend produces filled and hollow shapes that reflect the formatting I'm after, the actual plot itself only has filled circles.

```
##forest plot
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(outcome.var, coefficient, shape = factor(significant))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), colour = "grey1", shape = 20) +
  geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = 0, colour = "grey42", size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey98")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Using the helpful answers from @PoGibas, I could better understand the interpretation of the different layers and specifications. With some playing around I was eventually able to find the solution.

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(outcome.var, coefficient)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), shape = 32) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = significant), fill = 'white') +
  geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = 0, colour = "grey42", 
size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 19)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'black')) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey98")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is overcomplicated, but main problem is that you specify shape = `significant` in main `aes` and also specify **one** shape in  `geom_pointrange`.

I would write such code like this:

Code:

```
# Do you really need geom_point layer?
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(outcome.var, coefficient, shape = significant)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey42", size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16)) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey98")) +
    coord_flip()
```

Plot:

[image]

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(outcome.var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "J"), coefficient = c(-0.08, -0.01, -0.06, 0.02, 
0.01, 0.02, -0.08, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2), conf.low = c(-0.12, -0.03, 
-0.09, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, -0.1, -0.2, 0.05, 0.1), conf.high = c(-0.05, 
0.02, -0.03, 0.03, -0.01, 0.04, -0.06, 0, 0.2, 0.3), p.value = c(0.01, 
0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04), significant = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("nonsig", "sig"
), class = "factor"), label = c("First", "First", "First", "Second", 
"Second", "Second", "Third", "Third", "Fourth", "Fourth")), .Names = c("outcome.var", 
"coefficient", "conf.low", "conf.high", "p.value", "significant", 
"label"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Edit (OP asked to use color instead of shape):

```
ggplot(df, aes(outcome.var, coefficient)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = significant)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "grey42", size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey98")) +
    coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Regarding your code, I am wondering why if I replace the code `shape = significant` with `fill = significant`, and replace `scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 16))` with `scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'white'))` it does not produce a similar result?

Comment: @Paul `geom_point` (usual one) doesn't have `fill` status. Try playing with `color` instead.

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas. Do you know how I could write code that produced the same effect as your initial answer, but using `fill`specification rather than `shape` specification? Ideally I would like not to see the line underneath the data points.

Comment: Is there a way to drop the points from generated by the first layer `ggplot`?